# VBA Issue - Trying to make multiple cells mandatory to save an excel doc

Tags: vba, excel

Working on an excel doc and it requires a few cells to be filled before it can be saved. I was able to figure that out with the the following code.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(6, 5).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cell E6 requires user input", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If Cells(8, 5).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cell E8 requires user input", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If Cells(10, 5).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cell E10 requires user input", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The problem I am having is if specific cells are filled then other cells are required before the document can be saved. I have tried the isEmpty function but it still isn't working properly. Please help!

Comment: `If Len(Trim(Cells(1,1).Value))<>0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

Use `If Cells(1,1).Value <> ""` Then require the other cells like you've been doing. Like this:

```
If Cells(1,1).Value <> "" Then
    If Cells(10, 5).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cell E10 requires user input", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```